# How to find a text between two characters and replace it by a text between another two characters in notepad++?

Tags: python, notepad++

I have many file with the following structure

```
    @article{mehri_buckling_2016,
    title = {Buckling and vibration},
    volume = {303},
    issn = {00457825},
    url = {https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S004578251630010X},
    doi = {10.1016/j.cma.2016.01.017},
    pages = {75--100},
    journaltitle = {Computer Methods in Applied Mechanics and Engineering},
    shortjournal = {Computer Methods in Applied Mechanics and Engineering},
    author = {Mehri, M. and Asadi, H. and Wang, Q.},
    urldate = {2019-11-21},
    date = {2016-05},
    langid = {english}}
```

### I need to replace the words between  @article{......,   by the word between doi = {...}, .

For this example results should become

```
@article{10.1016/j.cma.2016.01.017,
        title = {Buckling and vibration},
        volume = {303},
        issn = {00457825},
        url = {https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S004578251630010X},
        doi = {10.1016/j.cma.2016.01.017},
        pages = {75--100},
        journaltitle = {Computer Methods in Applied Mechanics and Engineering},
        shortjournal = {Computer Methods in Applied Mechanics and Engineering},
        author = {Mehri, M. and Asadi, H. and Wang, Q.},
        urldate = {2019-11-21},
        date = {2016-05},
        langid = {english}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using notepad++:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `@article{\K.+?(,\R[\s\S]+?doi = {(.+?))(?=},)`
- Replace with: `$2$1`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/MusK8I/1)

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Excuse me. I have a another question which is related to this one.

Comment: It is possible to guide me. Many Thanks